# Jupyter command `jupyter-lab` not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have tried to install jupyter lab on my Kubuntu machine. 
If I install jupyter lab with 'pip3 install jupyter jupyterlab' the command 'jupyter notebook' works completly fine. But if I try to run 'jupyter lab' every time I get the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 230, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 133, in _jupyter_abspath
    'Jupyter command `{}` not found.'.format(jupyter_subcommand)
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-lab` not found.
```

What is wrong?

I tried to reinstall jupyter and jupyterlab multiple times with the same issue.

Comment: why it says 'jupyter-lab', it should give error as `Error executing Jupyter command 'lab': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Check your command again. it should be just `jupyter lab`, nothing else in between except a space.

Comment: askubuntu is a good forum to disscuss this issue

Comment: I just execute the command 'jupyter lab' without '-'.

Comment: try installing it using "conda"

Answer (score 80):

Its the space. Its always the space. Never ever use spaces within package name. Its always either namepart1-namepart2 or namepart1namepart2. This is because arguments are separated by space. So if you put space in between, it makes `pip` think that you want to install two different packages named `jupyter` and `lab`. Just use:

```
python -m pip install jupyterlab
```

Or simply:

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

No need to uninstall or reinstall anything. However to run jupyter lab server you might want to add spaces as follows:

```
jupyter lab
```

Comment: As usual on stackoverflow, any answer more than a year old will become obsolete so this is now incorrect except for older OSes. jupyter removed jupyter lab from its default install, so you must separately do `pip install jupyterlab`.

Comment: Dont understand whats obselete here? Works on Windows 11, Python 3.9

Comment: One important point here is to *look at the output of `pip install jupyterlab`*. Did it have any errors? I had. Perhaps some files were being used when tried to install. Login. Logout. Pip install jupyterlab again. And *volà*!

Answer (score 22):

When installing jupyterlab, we may get warning like this:

```
Installing collected packages: jupyterlab
  WARNING: The scripts jlpm, jupyter-lab, jupyter-labextension and jupyter-labhub are installed in '/home/tln/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed jupyterlab-3.0.14
```

So as per this warning, scripts like jupyter-lab will be unavailable unless added to the PATH.

Use below command to add these scripts to be able to use from command line:

```
tln@tln-X550LD:~$ export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

That's it. This worked fine for me.

Comment: Ah, as always reading the warning closely is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

In my case, the only way to fix this was to add the following directory to the `PATH` in Linux:

```
/home/ubuntu/.local/bin
```

Comment: @Tommy perhaps editing the answer, doesn't mean that the answer is not useful.

Comment: Fixed the problem for me having installed Jupyter lab using `pip` into userspace

Comment: the explanation is, during pip install, it does show similar warning about the path not set in linux system.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error on Windows 10. It was with `pip install jupyterlab`. Then after the error I uninstalled it with pip and reinstalled with "pip install jupyterlab". Everything worked flawlessly thereafter.

In your case you're using pip3. Try it as above or see if pip3 needs an update.

Comment: the `jupyter lab` package doesn't exist as it should be in one word (`jupyterlab`)

Comment: This comment saved me

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue. I solved it running pip install jupyterlab in prompt with admin privilegies.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to install with admin privileges . On win 10 pip install jupyterlab command with admin privileges fixed the jupyter lab not found error

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue and resolved it by installing with pip3

pip3 install jupyterlab;
jupyter lab

Answer (score 2):

Install with Anaconda

```
conda install -c conda-forge notebook
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

Answer (score 2):

Once installed you just have to run

```
pip install jupyterlab

~/.local/bin/jupyter-lab
```

and ready and open browser http://localhost:8888/lab

Ubuntu 22
Lubuntu 22

Answer (score 1):

If you face `-bash: jupyter-lab: command not found` or `-bash: jupyter: command not found`, etc., you can look for "jupyter-lab" and enter that full path instead.

Mac:

```
$ /Users/mark/venv/bin/jupyter-lab
```

Windows:

```
C:\mark\venv\Scripts\jupyter-lab.exe
```

Comment: I have a W10 system. For some weird reason (I'm not interested in figuring out why) I've got the jupyter-lab.exe installed in a different folder. In case you don't find that executable file, look for it using the Windows File Explorer.

Comment: I came back here just to tell you the best and quicker way to find the exe file. Open the command prompt and go to the C:/ drive. Type in `dir jupyter-lab.exe /s /p` This should give you the exact location of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error every time I forgot to activate the virtualenv jupyterlab was installed into. After activating the virtualenv, all's well.

With pip

```
$ source [path_to_venv]/bin/activate
```

With pipenv

```
$ pipenv shell
```

Then, with a prompt indicating an activated shell, you can enter your command

```
(venv) $ jupyter lab
```

With conda or other more holistic python environments, you probably use their gui to activate a virtualenv with jupyter and jupyterlab installed.

Answer (score 0):

well the problem is like this:

the `jupyterlab` module has not been packaged for debian, but the jupyterlab_server package has, named `python3-jupyterlab-server`.
please `sudo apt install python3-jupyterlab-server`.

then, as your user, run pip3 install jupyterlab, that will install it in your `~/.local/bin` a few programs, the missing `jupyter-lab` among them.

last, but not least, run `jupyter-serverextension enable --py jupyterlab`.

to be able to run `jupyter lab`, you first need to run `export PATH="/home/$(whoami)/.local/bin:"$PATH`. this command will run automatically if added to your `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu can not find the jupyter-lab because it is not in path.

in order to check the place of installment. run below command

```
find ~ -name jupyter-lab
```

possible result:   /home/soshiant/.local/bin/jupyter-lab

for adding a directory to the Linux path you can follow below link:

[How to add a directory to the PATH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path)

Answer (score 0):

if anyone still struggling ...
try:

> find ~ -name jupyter-lab

and then:

```
export PATH=[path]
```

then try again: `jupyter lab`
note:
don't add any extra spaces and PATH is case sensitive and if u still struggling just try to install any missing pkgs after hosting to the main path by opining another tab or changing the path to main.
and then host to **localhost:8888/lab**
that should works fine...

Answer (score 0):

I was using conda to install
`conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab`
and this error came about.

I simply used this command to get it to run.
`pip install jupyterlab`

Comment: In the short term this may fix things, but mixing and matching package managers is going to compound your issues in the related environments in the long run.

Comment: I already enabled my conda environment here and run that pip command. Is the issue you highlighted still be a potential problem?

Comment: I'm not following your latest comment but potentially you installed something with conda and the same thing with pip. It's just not a good idea to always do that.

Answer (score -2):

In my ubuntu installation this was qused by not using sudo before the install.

```
sudo pip install jupyterlab
```

If you already installed jupyterlab, and it dit not work, you can install again using sudo, you dont need to remove the old version first for it to work