# Jupyter command 'jupyter-lab' is not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, jupyter-lab

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\sklearn_tut.yml\Scripts\jupyter-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\sklearn_tut.yml\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 247, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\sklearn_tut.yml\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 134, in _jupyter_abspath
    'Jupyter command `{}` not found.'.format(jupyter_subcommand)
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-lab` not found.
```

I've run `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=xxx` and tried `jupyter-lab` and `jupyter lab`, both failed.

But later I installed `jupyter notebook` with `conda create -n python36 python=3.6` and it ran just fine. I can't understand what went wrong.

Comment: did you install jupyterlab too?
https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html

Comment: I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57677481/jupyter-command-jupyter-lab-not-found/58595179#58595179) answer that solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Anaconda is best for the beginners.  In my own experience with Anaconda, it reminded me of some of those PC anti-virus programs of years past which prevented me from performing many of my normal operation on the PC.   Once I was prevented from doing what I wanted with the computer, then that software was immediately uninstalled.

Once it became apparent that Anaconda was interfering with what I intended, then I uninstalled Anaconda and the associated python installation(s).  I reinstalled Python and then I used pip to install python packages and updates. I was doing the package management, which if I recall, Anaconda was interfering with my ability to use pip and making my control over python, virtual environments, etc.. difficult.

You can install the IRkernel without Anaconda.  Here are the steps to perform using RStudio:

```
>install.packages("devtools")  # install and then open library
>devtools::install_github("IRkernel/IRkernel") # can't recall, may need to open  library
>IRkernel::installspec() # All done.  Select a working director then type; 'Jupyter Lab'
```

IMO, everyone other than complete novices and neophytes, should be installing applications themselves and then doing the package management without using Anaconda.

Comment: Or use miniconda to get access to the conda command... In any case, the question didn't ask for IRKernel